# Mongodb count how often a value exist in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I try to write a query, which returns how often the value `keyword4` appears in my collection for the field `label`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54071d4312bf9ee0d67f7cf8"),
    "id" : "2",
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 60,
            "label" : "keyword3",
            "pos" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 89,
            "label" : "keyword4",
            "pos" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 49,
            "label" : "keyword4",
            "pos" : 3
        }
        ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5407sfkjsvnsvree9ee0d67f7cf8"),
    "id" : "3",
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 60,
            "label" : "keyword3",
            "pos" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 89,
            "label" : "keyword4",
            "pos" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 49,
            "label" : "keyword4",
            "pos" : 3
        }
        ]
},
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? If we can do your task for you? You have to show us what you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about here is "aggregating results" and for that you essentially use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/).

The steps are basically to match the documents that contain the value you want, filter the array content to only those matches, and then count the occurrences of that value for the field. The main operators here are [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) which takes query arguments such as `.find()` does, [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) which allows you to work with elements of the array, and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) which does the actual "aggregation", or indeed the "counting" for your element:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match the documents to reduce what you are processing
    { "$match": { "list.label": "keyword4" } },

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize or "un-join"
    { "$unwind": "$list" },

    // Match again to "filter" the array content
    { "$match": { "list.label": "keyword4" } },

    // Group your final results
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$list.label",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator here will "sum" the values it is supplied as an argument. In this case you can supply as basic value of `1` in order to represent the count to increment for each matched occurrence.

Also, the reason why there are "two" `$match` stages here is because of how MongoDB works and that they do separate things. The purpose of the first stage is to to match the "documents" that meet the condition. This is basically the same as the result from `.find()` since you are matching documents and not the sub-documents of the array. The statement only says this "contains" elements that meet the condition.

The second stage is processed "after" the `$unwind` which is where the remaining documents in the collection now appear as if they were "copied" for each element present in the array, and therefore that array element is no-longer an array but a singular field or "sub-document" from the array content.

Now as individual documents, the second `$match` will "filter" any elements that do not meet the condition. So now there are only "list.label" values matching the specified value. You don't want to omit the first `$match` since that would mean processing that `$unwind` over every document in your collection, whether the array element contained a match or not. This means you are not doing "un-necessary" work by processing things that will not possibly count towards the result.

For a better understanding and introduction to using the aggregation framework, the [SQL to aggregation mapping page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the documentation is worth looking at, at least for some common examples and more directly if you are used to the SQL form.

Also it is a good idea to generally familiarize yourself with the general [aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and understand their function. This is a useful tool and essentially the counterpart to general queries. So well worth learning, and use it well.c